# Datatables doesn't recognize pageLength for number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm simply trying to have only 15 rows when I bring my data up. For some reason it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $('.datatable').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/ajaxI/gd/1/54",
        "data": function (d) {

        }
    },
    "paging": true,
    "searching": false,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, -1], [15, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 15,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": ' &nbsp; <img src="/img/ajax-loader-large.gif" alt="Loading" width="26" height="26" />'
    },
    "autoWidth" : false        }
});
```

All my data shows up for some weird reason.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

On the table element, use:

data-page-length='15'  eg

```
<table id="table" class="" data-page-length='15' >
```